# iOS 5 XCODE 4.3.2 Storyboard. How do I insert a new view before an existing table view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, tableview

To start, I'm really new to iOS and Xcode. I've worked through several demos and read quite a bit on the dev site.

My current app started as a navigation controller > Table view controller (master view) > Detail view.  It's a basic menu in table view that can drill down to an items detail showing picture, price, description etc. I followed (mostly) the tutorial from the iOS dev library "your second iOS app" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1
in addition I did make some implementation changes as far as layout and properties, but in the end it functions perfectly.

Now, after the fact, I've decided I don't like the app's entry point to be the table view. Rather I would prefer to enter to a view controller with some other buttons, one of which will take you to the menu.

My problem is as follows;
 I delete the relationship "root view controller" between the navigation controller and the table view, and then I reconnect it from navigation controller to my new view. I think link a button with a push segue to the old table view.
Now the app still builds fine, however it crashes upon running with the following error
 "-[UIViewController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6ed60
2012-05-09 16:51:28.618 [16513:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDataController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6ed60'
*** First throw call stack: "

It appears that the setter is getting some bad data. so I'm going to guess it's somehow a problem with the old rootview not being valid, I really don't know enough to fix this. Please help.

sorry no rep to post a picture, if you need one let me know and I'll host it somewhere.

Comment: Ok I'm getting close. I made the FirstViewController class as suggested.
`#import "DriftMasterViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuItemDataController *dataController;`

now the interface doesn't crash, however it doesn't show my menu items in the tableview anymore. not seeing the correct instance?

Comment: **UPDATE SOLVED..I think**   So I added a prepareForSegue in my FirstViewController.m `DriftMasterViewController *masterViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    masterViewController.dataController = self.dataController;` and everything is working as expected.. is this how it should be done or  am i just hacking here?

Comment: What you are doing there is getting the controller from the storyboard directly, which is the correct way if that segue specifically moves to the controller you want to reference. The other way is to ask the storyboard directly to give you the viewcontroller with a specified identifier (which you also set in the properties in the storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the UIViewController that is your initial screen doesn't know what setDataController means. You can resolve this by subclassing UIViewController (call it FirstViewController or something) and then setting the class of your initial view controller to that subclass in storyboard. Then, in the header, give your FirstViewController a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) DataController *dataController`. There's probably more steps to getting it all up and running but the main thing is that you should be working with a subclass of UIViewController, not an instance of the class itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have a class for the orig tableViewController so I just tried to reuse that as the class for the new viewController. getting new error.

.h
`@class MenuItemDataController;
@interface DriftMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuItemDataController *dataController;`

NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the nib but didnt get a UITableView

Comment: i think the problem is in my appdelagate.m can you see my comments in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the last version in where your Table view was the root. And simply drag a new viecontroller on the story board anywhere. then you will see an arrow pointing to the table view, drag that arrow to the new viewcontroller.

Comment: yes that is what I tried first, I can't drag the arrow in xcode 4.3.2 I have to delete it and make another one **"I delete the relationship "root view controller" between the navigation controller and the table view, and then I reconnect it from navigation controller to my new view."** Simply doing this is what causes the error.

Comment: are you not using storyboard? you can directly declare any view as the initial view controller in the property inspector, third tab from right to left, there is a "Is initial View Controller". And i think i understand what you mean, when you added the table view it probably came with another viewcontroller that conects to the table view right? On the same property inspector you can find on the connections the one that says delegate and datasource or something like that, just point them to the correct instance that will now manage your methods.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you are describing is what i've done from the start, here is a picture [link](http://imgur.com/8cpwr) 
I think the problem is just in my appdelegate.m because before I added the new view controller, the navcontroller would return its root view controller which was the  table view, now it's returning the UIViewController. in the line `firstViewController.dataController = aDataController;` the firstviewcontroller is the UIViewcontroller, not the tableviewcontroller. how can i fix this?

Comment: in the pic you gave me, on the line //try. type NSLog(@"%@",firstViewController); What is the output in the console?

Comment: also i dont think you are using the navigation controller correctly, have you read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html ? Oh and my bet is that on your app delegate you are NOT getting the correct type of controller, with the result of the nslog you can see what you are actually refering to.

Comment: the console shows 2012-05-11 08:58:01.537 Drift Mobile Eatery[17779:f803] <FirstViewController: 0x6e1e320>

I haven't read that entirely, I will now. 
Also, i'm still using `DriftMasterViewController *firstViewController = (DriftMasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];` in my appdelegate, should I change it to something like `FirstViewController *firstViewController = (FirstViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: so basically, my "firstViewController' variable is an instance of my FirstViewController class.

Comment: A navigation controller holds an array of its viewcontrollers, the problem you had occurs because whatever is at object index 0 ([[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]) is not of the type you expect, so it doesnt have the method you are asking for, and an exception is thrown, by using NSLog you can see what kind of controller you are getting. when you do this (DriftMasterViewController *) you are casting the result, so you are telling xcode that the object at that index IS of that type. you can use a for cycle to nslog all objects in the stack to see what you got there.